# Can't create bucket on S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm working on a S3 server on Linode with the aws-sdk-php library, and for some reason I can't figure out I'm unable to create a bucket. There are already 2 created buckets, and I know the connection is working because I can manipulate and work on those buckets at will.
However, when I try to create a new bucket, I get a 400 error message. My code:

```
define('AWS_KEY', 'my-key');
define('AWS_SECRET_KEY', 'my-secret-key');
$ENDPOINT = 'http://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com';
$client = new S3Client([
    'region' => 'eu-central-1',
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'endpoint' => $ENDPOINT,
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => AWS_KEY,
        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY
    ],
    'use_path_style_endpoint' => true
]);
try {
    $result = $client->createBucket(['Bucket' => 'test']);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've tried the following options for calling the createBucket method:

```
$result = $client->createBucket([
    'ACL' => 'private',
    'Bucket' => 'test', 
    'CreateBucketConfiguration' => [
        'LocationConstraint' => 'eu-central-1'
    ]
]);
```

```
$result = $client->createBucket([
    'Bucket' => 'test', 
    'LocationConstraint' => 'eu-central-1'
]);
```

And no matter which one I run, I get the following error message:

Error executing "CreateBucket" on "http://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/test"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT http://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/test` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: InvalidLocationConstraintThe specified location-const (truncated...) InvalidLocationConstraint (client): The specified location-constraint is not valid - InvalidLocationConstraintThe specified location-constraint is not validtesttx00000000000000a3d5d24-00606e2f87-1549e3f-default1549e3f-default-default

I'm new to this sort of thing in PHP, that's why I'm trying to do everything 'by the book' (following the documentation as closely as possible), so I really don't understand what's going on.

EDIT: I've found even more problems associated with this. Using CyberDuck I can manage the S3, through which I created some buckets (say, 'test'). using aws-sdk-php I can list them correctly using listBuckets and even put objects in them, but some functions like getBucketCors() give an error message saying:

Error executing "GetBucketCors" on "http://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/test?cors"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET http://eu-central-1.linodeobjects.com/test?cors` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: NoSuchCORSConfigurationtestNoSuchCORSConfigurationtesttx00000000000000a965dee-00606f69c5-1549e27-default1549e27-default-default

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem.
The solution was to change the *region* parameter from *eu-central-1* back to the default Value *us-east-1*.
After that, i could create the bucket.
Our admin tells me, the default value on the netapp is *us-east-1* even too and could now match with the s3client.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting s3BucketEndpoint to false when creating an S3 client and specifying the region as '*us-east-1*'. It appears that buckets can only be created with the S3 SDK in Linode in this region.

```
new S3({
   endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint(`https://${endpoint}`),
   region,
   credentials,
   s3ForcePathStyle: true,
   s3BucketEndpoint: false,
})
```